# Multiple Domain classes + searchable plugin + grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am developing one application, in which there are more than 130 domain classes and i used those classes for database. I have class called request. In this class, there are more than 30 objects and 22 objects are references to other classes.

When I try to execute a search query on domain class, it throws a methodMissing exception and returns null value.

But I used same search method on another domain for testing and it worked perfectly.

So what's the problem with this?

Comment: If you have a class called `request`, that could easily be messing with the Grails injecting magic (depending on where you are executing the query, etc...). I don't think you will get a meaningful answer without posting some code, though.

Comment: Code is like that Request{all objects of other class, string objects,,} I i m just making this domain as statis searchable { all true}. when i calllin Method Request.search(param.str) it will through Method Missing Exception.  Is it need that all reference domain classes are static searchable true??

Comment: Error: Search Query is: (subject:Value, description:Value, symptoms:Value)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: request.Request.search() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [(subject:Value, description:Value, symptoms:Value)]

Answer (score 1):

After apply Request.search(str), it will generate exception like this...

Incident Query: (subject:Value, description:Value, symptoms:Value)

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:

servicedesk.request.Request.search() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)

values: [(subject:Value, description:Value, symptoms:Value)]

Answer (score 0):

If you have an object of type Request like this

```
    def request = Request.get(1) //or however you get your object
```

Unless search is a static method you would call search like this:

```
    request.seach(str)
```

Not

```
    request.Request.search(str)
```

I also agree with Seth - probably not the best idea to call your class Request...